# Angular4 form controls validation does not work anymore after an update

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here is how I used to use form control validation with Angular2 / Ionic

```
  <ion-label *ngIf="email.invalid && email.touched">
    Your email address is invalid
  </ion-label>
  <ion-input
    type="email"
    placeholder="e-mail"
    name="email"
    #email="ngModel"
    required
    email
    (ionFocus)="deleteHugoError(hugoEmailField)"
    ngModel>
  </ion-input>
```

It was working as expected: as long as the user was typing something in the first time, he didn't have any error message.

I recently updated to Angular4, and the new behaviour is not the one expected: as soon as the user starts typing an email, he can see the error message.

I checked the documentation about `touched` but it seems to be the same than before.
Besides, when inspecting the code, I can definitely see `ng-untouched` when typing an email...
Any idea? Thanks.

---

**EDIT** (thanks Alex Beugnet)

It is a bug introduced in Ionic since v 3.4: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12102

Comment: are you using reactive forms ?

Comment: @RahulSingh nope, template driven forms.

Comment: We need your validators then

Comment: @AlexBeugnet to the point there has been some change in validator method i vaguely remember can you point us to that

Comment: @AlexBeugnet I updated my post with it.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched

This might be what you are looking for

Comment: I read about that, but it was already what I was doing. Adding `dirty` does not change the problem actually. The error message should not appear because I guess the `blur` event related to the `touched` attribute should not be fire. (it worked perfectly before the update).

Comment: Try adding a spy to detect which one of them is causing this issue : https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel

the `touched` directive definetly didn't change, so either something else is interacting with the html attributes beforehand or the `invalid` directive is not working as intended

Comment: Besides, when inspecting the code, I can definitely see `ng-untouched` when typing an email...

Comment: Does it work correctly with a regular input ?  Might be coming from the `ion-input`

Comment: Did you see that ionic issue ? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12102
If it stays untouched while typing then it is definitely coming from the `invalid` mail directive

Comment: Oh my mistake, it does not stay untouched. My problem is *exactly* this issue, thanks for this. I guess I'll have to wait for a patch.